# React Native Babel Tape SyntaxError Invalid or unexpected token with PNG files

Tags: reactjs, react-native, node.js-tape, babel-register

I am writing an App using React Native, and I would like to test the App components with Tape and JSX syntax, so I think 'babel' is a must.

However when I run `tape -r babel-register tests/**/*.js`, I received the infamous `SyntaxError` with a PNG file.

```
/<redacted>/node_modules/react-native-router-flux/images/back_chevron.png:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { �PNG

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:152:10)
    ...
```

With an intention to search before asking, I have found a lot about ReactJS (which is about Webpack issues) and solutions with Jest (by setting `jest` in `package.json`).

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0/decorator-support",
    "react",
    "es2015",
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-react-jsx-source"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Please feel free to comment on what logs / versions / config files I could add to this question!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the version of react-native-router flux to 3.43.0.